# React Native Galio Framework navbar

Tags: react-native, font-awesome

I am using React-Native, Galio framework.

In the Navbar I have some Icons and I would like to enlarge them... is that possible?

```
import { Button, Block, NavBar, Input, Text, theme } from 'galio-framework'; 
<NavBar
                        back={back}
                        title={title}
                        style={styles.navbar}
                        transparent={transparent}
                        right={this.renderRight()}
                        rightStyle={{ alignItems: 'center' }}
                        leftStyle={{ paddingTop: 3, flex: 0.3 }}
                        leftIconName={back ? 'chevron-circle-left' : 'navicon'}
                        leftIconFamily="font-awesome"
                        leftIconColor={
                            white ? materialTheme.COLORS.NAVICON : theme.COLORS.ICON
                        }
                        titleStyle={[
                            styles.title,
                            { color: theme.COLORS[white ? 'WHITE' : 'ICON'] },
                        ]}
                        onLeftPress={this.handleLeftPress}
                    />
```

I would like chevron-circle-left and navicon to be slightly larger..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not possible by any of the props because if you check the code for the [renderleft](https://github.com/galio-org/galio/blob/master/src/NavBar.js) the icon size is calculate using the theme size

```
              <Icon
                family={leftIconFamily || "evilicons"}
                color={leftIconColor || theme.COLORS.ICON}
                size={theme.SIZES.BASE * 1.0625}
                name={leftIconName || (back ? 'chevron-left' : 'navicon')}
              />
```

However you can use a workaround as you are already providing these props manually you can provide this as the 'left' prop with your custom size which will help you render your own left side.

Comment: heh.. thanks! that was quick one... size={theme.SIZES.BASE * leftIconSize || theme.SIZES.BASE * 1.0625}.. worked as a charm.